# Web Safe Area (optimal resolution) for web app design

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, cross-browser, screen-resolution

I'm in the process of designing a new web app and I'm wondering for what 'Web Safe Area' should I optimize the app layout and design. By Web Safe Area I mean the actual area available to display the website in the browser (which is influenced by monitor resolution as well as the space taken up by the browser and OS)

I did some investigation and thinking on my own but wanted to share this to see what the general opinion is. Here is what I found:

**Optimal Display Resolution:**

- **w3schools web stats** seems to be the
  most referenced source (however they
  state that these are results from
  their site and is biased towards tech
  savvy users)
- http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php
  (aggregate data from something like
  15,000 different sites that use their
  tracking services)
- [StatCounter Global Stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-na-monthly-201002-201101) > Display
  Resolution (Stats are based on
  aggregate data collected by
  StatCounter on a sample exceeding 15
  billion pageviews per month collected
  from across the StatCounter network
  of more than 3 million websites)
- NetMarketShare Screen Resolutions (marketshare.hitslink.com) (a
  web analytics consulting firm, they
  get data from browsers of site
  visitors to their on-demand network
  of live stats customers. The data is
  compiled from approximately 160
  million visitors per month)

**Display Resolution Summary:** There is a bit of variation between the above sources but in general as of Jan 2011 looks like 1024x768 is about 20%, while ~85% have a higher resolution of at least 1280x768 (1280x800 is the most common of these with 15-20% of total web, depending on the source; 1280x1024 and 1366x768 follow behind with 9-14% of the share). My guess would be that the higher resolution values will be even more common if we filter on North America, and even higher if we filter on N.American corporate users (unfortunately I couldn't find any free geographically filtered statistics). Another point to note is that the 1024x768 desktop user population is likely lower than the aforementioned 20%, seeing as the iPad (1024x768 native display) is likely propping up those number.

My recommendation would be to optimize around the 1280x768 constraint (*note: 1280x768 is actually a relatively rare resolution, but I think it's a valid constraint range considering that 1366x768 is relatively common and 1280 is the most common horizontal resolution).

**Browser + OS Constraints:**
To further add to the constraints we have to subtract the space taken up by the browser (assuming IE, which is the most space consuming) and the OS (assuming WinXP-Win7):

- Win7 has the biggest taskbar footprint at a height of 40px (XP's and Vista's is 30px)
- The default IE8 view uses up 25px at the bottom of the screen with the status bar and a further 120px at the top of the screen with the windows title bar and the browser UI (assuming the default 'favorites' toolbar is present, it would instead be 91px without the favorites toolbar).
- Assuming no scrollbar, we also loose a total of 4px horizontally for the window outline.

This means that we are left with 583px of vertical space and 1276px of horizontal. In other words, a Web Safe Area of 1276 x 583

Is this a correct line of thinking?

I tried to Google some design best practices but most still talk about designing around 1024x768 which seems to be quickly disappearing.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like pretty good thinking. I tend to design for 1024x768 because of Netbooks and new things like iPads, but assuming 1280 resolution for normal desktop users seems fairly realistic these days.

Answer (score 1):

As Bigood pointed out, http://browsersize.googlelabs.com was moved into Google Analytics.  However, perspectives have also changed.

Rather than trying to create a page with fixed, "optimal" dimensions, a more modern approach is to design Web sites as responsive pages that adapt to different screen resolutions.  [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is one of many CSS and component libraries that make creating responsive sites easier.

Further, other tools make it easy to test Web page response at different resolutions. For example, Chrome's Developer Tools now allows developers to emulate specific devices or manually set specific screen dimensions and get a reasonable view of how the Web page will appear to users at that resolution:

[image: Chrome Device/Resolution Emulation]

Internet Explorer's Developer Tools allow you to re-size the browser to preset or custom, specific dimensions.

In conclusion, nowadays, there is no "Web Safe Area for web app design."  Expectations for mobile devices coexisting with desktop browsers has led the industry to stress responsive sites over those designed with "optimal resolutions."

Comment: Broken link. Browsersize is now part of Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more looking around I found a really useful site that can show you how your website will appear on multiple browser types (and versions) as well as on different OS's: http://browsershots.org/

Another caveat to my line of thinking above is that different browsers actually take up different amounts of pixels based on the OS they're running on. For example, under WinXP IE8 takes up 142px on top of the screen (instead the aforementioned 120px for Win7) because the file menu shows up by default on XP while in Win7 the file menu is hidden by default. So it looks like on WinXP + IE8 the Web Safe Area would be a mere 572px (768px-142-30-24=572)

Again, I'm really surprised that I couldn't find this type of 'exploration' anywhere on the web. Lots of websites talk about designing for 1024x768, but that's only half the equation! There is no mention of browser/OS influences on the actual area you have to display the site/app.